# Get a value from the database authentication with a custom context

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, scaffolding

I am trying to recover the value of the user who is logged on the site but I am currently blocked.

I use .Net core 2.1 with EF Core. I created a context called `jakformulaireContext` and also `jakformulaireUser`.

I have to send an email to confirm that a user has registered to an event but I can not find the piece of code allowing me to recover the field "email" which is in the database.

In the scaffolding part which contains the Register controller I succeeded because I would recover the value of the field "email" but here I am in a controller that is located outside of Account.

So I tried to do a find but it does not seem to be the right method because I get a Task <> while I just want a string.

```
var user = _userManager.FindByEmailAsync ("jon@live.be");
```

Would you have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an async method it will return a Task. So what you need to do is wait until that method is finished. The way to do it is:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync ("jon@live.be");
```

More information about [async/wait](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

Comment: Thx for your help! The only problem with this way is that i'm not supposed to already have jon@live.be, i have hardcoded it for my tests.
What could i use to make the find?

Comment: I think what i need is something like the id or the username of the logged user, then i could make my find.

Comment: Okey i found how to do it! I just had to do var test = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;